# Positive examples of central bank interest rates adjustments policies

Tags: interest-rate, central-banking

I'm looking for sources, maybe scientific articles, that study the effectiveness of central bank interest rate adjustments. Specifically, I'm looking for some kind of a proof by example, where a country which had stable policies regarding the adjustments in a larger period of time received consistent results in the effects of these adjustments; especially when adjusting for global crises.

Which countries are best examples for a positive role of adjusting central bank interest rates?